# SQLAlchemy - Self-referential many-to-many relationship in custom declarative base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am building a Python application that uses SQLAlchemy, and I am trying to implement a many-to-many relationship between a custom declarative base class and itself (self-referential). But I cannot get it to work. I am attaching the code down below, as well as the error traceback, in case anyone can help :) All the entities of the model already extended from this base class, and the application was working so far, in case that helps.

Thanks!!

---

Code (non-functional):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import String


permissions = Table(
    'permissions', MetaData(),
    Column('origin_id', String, ForeignKey('bases.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('target_id', String, ForeignKey('bases.id'), primary_key=True)
)


class Base:

    __tablename__ = 'bases'
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'
    }

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    targets = relationship(
        'Base',
        secondary='permissions',
        primaryjoin='Base.id == permissions.c.origin_id',
        secondaryjoin='Base.id == permissions.c.target_id',
        backref='origins'

        # Reference:
        # https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many
    )


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

Traceback:

```
    class ContactMethod(Base):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.4.23-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py", line 72, in __init__
    _as_declarative(reg, cls, dict_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.4.23-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 126, in _as_declarative
    return _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(registry, cls, dict_, None, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.4.23-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 177, in setup_mapping
    return cfg_cls(registry, cls_, dict_, table, mapper_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.4.23-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 299, in __init__
    self._scan_attributes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.4.23-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 511, in _scan_attributes
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper properties (i.e. deferred,column_property(), relationship(), etc.) must be declared as @declared_attr callables on declarative mixin classes.  For dataclass field() objects, use a lambda:
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? All classes should have their own M-N relationships? Or a generic M-N relationship between all classes? Or something else completely?

Comment: Were you able to follow the advice given in my answer?

Comment: @van I would like to be able to set a relationship between any two entities of the model, so it would be a generic M-N relationship between all classes. Not working so far...

Comment: Well, in this case you should really consider using [Inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html). The purpose of the *declarative* Base is not the same as having the base object in terms of _inheritance_.

Comment: Thanks @van !! Although I tried that too. First by creating a class that inherits from Base and incorporates this relationship, so that all the other classes inherit from this new class. Also, I tried creating a [Mixin](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html), so that all classes would inherit first from Base, then from the Mixin. Neither of those worked...

Comment: ok, i will add sample code as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a working self-containing example:

```
## Imports
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, as_declarative, declared_attr, relationship

## Configuration
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)


@as_declarative()
class Base(object):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()


permissions = Table(
    "permissions",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("origin_id", String, ForeignKey("model_base.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("target_id", String, ForeignKey("model_base.id"), primary_key=True),
)


## Model definitions
class ModelBase(Base):
    __tablename__ = "model_base"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": type,
        "polymorphic_identity": None,
    }

    targets = relationship(
        "ModelBase",
        secondary="permissions",
        primaryjoin="model_base.c.id == permissions.c.origin_id",
        secondaryjoin="model_base.c.id == permissions.c.target_id",
        backref="origins",
        # lazy="raise",
    )


class ClassA(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "class_a"
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "class_a"}
    id = Column(ForeignKey("model_base.id"), primary_key=True)

    name = Column(String)


class ClassB(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "class_b"
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "class_b"}
    id = Column(ForeignKey("model_base.id"), primary_key=True)

    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(Integer)


## Tests
def _main():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        print("=" * 80)

        # data
        a1, a2 = [ClassA(name="a1"), ClassA(name="a2")]
        b1, b2 = [ClassB(name="b1"), ClassB(name="b2", value=3)]
        session.add_all([a1, a2, b1, b2])
        session.flush()

        a1.targets.append(a2)
        a1.targets.append(b1)
        a1.targets.append(b2)
        print(b2.targets)
        print(b2.origins)

        session.commit()
        session.expunge_all()

        print("=" * 80)
        a1 = session.query(ClassA).first()
        print(a1)
        print(a1.origins)
        print(a1.targets)

        session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much @van !!!

Comment: Additional note about this solution:

Let's say that you have two classes that inherit from ModelBase: Person and Object. And let's assume that a Person can own several Objects, through a many-to-one relationship, and that relationship has a cascade behaviour (if the Person gets deleted, all its Objects get deleted too).

It seems that, when the Person is deleted (either from the Persons table or the ModelBases table), all associated rows in the Objects table are deleted too, but the ModelBase rows from which those Objects inherit are not deleted. Haven't figured out how to fix that yet.

Comment: You need to add `cascade="all, delete",` to the relationship definition from the. Read more on [Using delete cascade with many-to-many relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#using-delete-cascade-with-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example of what the error output recommends to remediate:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

class Base:
    ...
    @declared_attr
    def targets(cls):
        return relationship(
            'Base',
            secondary='permissions',
            primaryjoin='Base.id == permissions.c.origin_id',
            secondaryjoin='Base.id == permissions.c.target_id',
            backref='origins'
        )
    ...
```

Sidenote: you can use the `as_declarative` mixin on your base class as a shortcut.

## References

Augmenting the base: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#augmenting-the-base

declared_attr: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr

as_declarative: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.as_declarative

Comment: I already checked the documentation. The problem is that every solution seems to have some issue attached, and none of them end up working...